# Expected behavior? aws_s3_bucket_notification in a module, used in a for_each, swap places every time I apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I have a terraform module that contains an `aws_s3_bucket_notification` on a single bucket. The module is used outside in a `for_each` loop. The bucket is the same for all deployed notification resources that are generated by the `for_each`. The notification resources differ only in `filter_prefix` and `lambda_function_arn`.

Currently there are two configurations in the `for_each` loop, so two iterations, let's call them `"foo"` and `"bar"`. Each module that is generated by this `for_each` gets a different name in the terraform state like `module.my_module["foo"]` and `module.my_module["bar"]`. So I'm ending up with two actual notifications:

- `module.my_module["foo"].aws_s3_bucket_notification.my_notification`
- `module.my_module["bar"].aws_s3_bucket_notification.my_notification`

Weirdly enough, every time I do `terraform apply` the `aws_s3_bucket_notification`s swap places. Every second turn the notification for `"foo"` listens on the `filter_prefix` for `bar` and executes the lambda for `bar`, and vice versa. The other times the association between module name and notification config is correct.

Technically, this is okay-ish. It just messes up the terraform state and leads to planned changes that would not normally be necessary. It smells.

Is this an expected behavior? Or is it potentially a bug? Or is my approach wrong in the first place to have `aws_s3_bucket_notification`s on the same bucket with different lambdas and `filter_prefix`es in a module that is used in a `for_each`?

## Update 1

Here is some "pseudi-anonymized" output of the current state (`terraform state show`) and the plan that shall be applied. That does not look like expected behavior to me.

```bash
--- terraform show state 'module.my_module["AAAA"].module.my_submodule.aws_s3_bucket_notification.my_notification'
# module.my_module["AAAA"].module.my_submodule.aws_s3_bucket_notification.my_notification:
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "my_notification" {
    bucket      = "my_bucket"
    eventbridge = false
    id          = "my_bucket"

    lambda_function {
        events              = [
            "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
        ]
        filter_prefix       = "some_prefix_AAAA"
        id                  = "tf-s3-lambda-...00000001"
        lambda_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account_id>:function:some_lambda_AAAA"
    }
}

--- terraform show state 'module.my_module["BBBB"].module.my_submodule.aws_s3_bucket_notification.my_notification'
# module.my_module["BBBB"].module.my_submodule.aws_s3_bucket_notification.my_notification:
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "my_notification" {
    bucket      = "my_bucket"
    eventbridge = false
    id          = "my_bucket"

    lambda_function {
        events              = [
            "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
        ]
        filter_prefix       = "some_prefix_BBBB"
        id                  = "tf-s3-lambda-...00000002"
        lambda_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account_id>:function:some_lambda_BBBB"
    }
}

--- terraform plan
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.my_module["AAAA"].module.my_submodule.aws_s3_bucket_notification.my_notification will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "my_notification" {
        id          = "my_bucket"
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ lambda_function {
          ~ filter_prefix       = "some_prefix_BBBB" -> "some_prefix_AAAA"
            id                  = "tf-s3-lambda-...00000002"
          ~ lambda_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account_id>:function:some_lambda_BBBB" -> "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account_id>:function:some_lambda_AAAA"
            # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
        }
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

## Update 2

The reason for this behavior is apparently that there can only be ONE `aws_s3_bucket_notification` for each bucket.

Now I'll have to figure out how to statically create that one empty `aws_s3_bucket_notification` resource, while dynamically creating the corresponding `lambda_function` entries from a completely different module/codebase.

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: I would love to add relevant code. Unfortunately, I'm under NDA. I'll see if I can come up with some "made up" code that resembles what I have.

Comment: The map I'm iterating over with for_each is as unordered as a map in terraform usually is. I understand the index/key should prevent the swapping. The notification created in the "foo" iteration should be associated with the "foo" module and "bar" accordingly. But for every second apply it doesn't...

Comment: Does the highlighted note at the top of the `aws_s3_bucket_notification` documentation apply? From your description, it seems like it does.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it does... How goes the saying? He who can read has a clear advantage. Yeah, now I need a solution for the problem that I have a single notification resource in one place and dynamic trigger information in a completely different place...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is apparently that there can only be **one** `aws_s3_bucket_notification` for each bucket.

This is also mentioned in the [`aws_s3_bucket_notification` documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_notification) in Terraform in the note at the top of the document.

Comment: Yes, but that does not answer how to create dynamically all the lambda_function inside the unique `aws_s3_bucket_notification` resource. When I duplicate the lambda section, all triggers goes to the same lambda arn instead of using the arn variable.